# how can i track a bitcoin sent to someone claiming not to have seen it

Tags: blockchain

i transfer bitcoin to account 3CcKWXXC1BXvctthfaFyeWYXG8mZWT1HUU and he claim not to have seen it for 2 days. i have tried to look for the causes of this but i can see that it has been deliver to him just pretending not to have seen it

Comment: I think you've mistaken bitcoin stackexchange for a support channel. I'd suggest going to the help channels of whichever wallet you have used.

Comment: @tuxcanfly No, this is on topic.

Answer (score 1):

There's no evidence of any such transfer. Check [this page](https://blockchain.info/address/3CcKWXXC1BXvctthfaFyeWYXG8mZWT1HUU) and you'll see.